# Google Tag Manager Parse Error. Primary Expression

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to save this Custom Javascript Variable within Google Tag Manager and return this error each time:

Error at line 2, character 4: Parse error. primary expression expected

```
var prodID = function pID() {
return document.querySelector(".no-display > input[name=product]").value;
}();
```

Can someone help me? I believe I have a primary expression.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue in Google tag manger, I simple re wrote the code to be :

```
function() {
  return document.querySelector(".no-display > input[name=product]").value;
}
```

Comment: Your issue was that you were immediately invoking your function (see last line of the code snippet in the question). I had the same error message when I failed to wrap the code in a function() definition.

Answer (score 1):

All code in a custom javascript variable should be within function() {}, or you will get this error.

Here's the documentation from Google:

> This field should be a JavaScript function that returns a value using
>   the 'return' statement. If the function does not explicitly return a
>   value, it will return undefined and your container may not behave as
>   expected. Below is an example of this field:

```
function() {
     var now = new Date();
     return now.getTime();   
}
```