# Get difference between 2 dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var date1 = new Date("04.11.2016");
var date2 = new Date("19.11.2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Trying get different between those Dates, but my date format is that "04.11.2016", Result show NaN

Comment: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Have you tried logging dates? `date2` is null

Comment: `date2` is invalid date. You have passed 'DD-MM-YYYY', but it should be 'MM-DD-YYYY' (11.19.2016)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var date1 = new Date("11/04/2016");
var date2 = new Date("11/19/2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

change the format of date.

it should be **MM/DD/YYYY**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `moment.js` library:

```
var date1 = moment('04.11.2016', 'MM.DD.YYYY'),
    date2 = moment('19.11.2016', 'MM.DD.YYYY'),
    diffDays = date2.diff(date1, 'days'); // you can wrap it in Math.abs()
```

The ugly js way:

```
var input1 = '04.11.2016',
    parts1 = input1.split('.'),
    date1 = new Date(parts1[2], parts1[1], parts1[0]),
    input2 = '19.11.2016',
    parts2 = input2.split('.'),
    date2 = new Date(parts2[2], parts2[1], parts2[0]),
    timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()),
    diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution which uses a function called `getDate` to convert the date string of the format `"04.11.2016"` to a JavaScript Date object.

```js
function getDate(dateStr) {
  var arr = dateStr.split('.');

  return new Date(arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]);
}

var start = getDate("04.11.2016");
var end = getDate("19.11.2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
console.log('Number of days: ' + diffDays);
```

In order to use this code to create a Custom JavaScript Variable in Google Tag Manager, you can modify the above code or the one which you choose to be inside a function - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418777/google-tag-manager-parse-error-primary-expression).

[image: Custom JavaScript Variable in Google Tag Manager]

[image: Custom JavaScript Variable in Google Tag Manager]

Comment: @MargubAlam, could you post the actual error message and in which environment did you execute that code ?

Comment: this error  Error at line 7, character 1: Parse error. ')' expected
- http://screencast.com/t/KQLEF0yF8E

Comment: @MargubAlam, check my updated answer, I had to figure out in which environment you executed that code, through google search I was able to know that it is called Google Tag Manager, just saw it for the very first time and followed your screen shots to create Custom JavaScript

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. You can take a tour of Stack Overflow from here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Change the Month and Date order First should be month then date... **MM/DD/YYYY**

```js
var date1 = new Date("11.04.2016");
var date2 = new Date("11.19.2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second date is incorrect. Parser is considering this format MM.DD.YYY and you have supplied out of range month.

```js
var date1 = new Date("04.11.2016");
var date2 = new Date("09.11.2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

A date consists of a year, a month, a day, an hour, a minute, a second, and milliseconds.

Date objects are created with the new Date() constructor.

There are 4 ways of initiating a date:

new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

so you can split them and then use it

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first two lines as below

```
var date1 = new Date(2016,11,4);
var date2 = new Date(2016,11,19);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new date("mm dd yyyy")` format was wrong

```js
(function () {
var date1 = new Date("11 04 2016");
var date2 = new Date("11 19 2016");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

JS expects date to in `MM-DD-YYYY` and not `DD-MM-YYYY`. Ideal way would be to use moment.js, but you can use something like this:

```js
function createCustomDate(dateString){
  var dateArr = dateString.split(/[^0-9]/).reverse().join("-")
  return new Date(dateArr);
}

var dateStr1 = "04.11.2016";
var dateStr2 = "19.11.2016";
var date1 = createCustomDate(dateStr1);
var date2 = createCustomDate(dateStr2);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("19.11.2016");
```

this is **Invalid Date**.  So, difference is be NaN .

change the format to `mm/dd/yyyy` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment.js`,

```
d = moment('11.16.2016') // here date format was in "MM.DD.YYYY"
e = moment('11.04.2016') // here date format was in "MM.DD.YYYY"
getDiffbydays = e.diff(d,'days') // get diff by days you can use day
getDiffbyyears = e.diff(d,'year') // get diff by years you can use year 
getDiffbymonth = e.diff(d,'month') // get diff by months you can use month
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const day = Math.abs(new Date("11 04 2016").valueOf() - new Date("11 19 2016").valueOf())/1000/60/60/24;
console.log(day)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).