# GTM - Custom HTML - Parse error. primary expression expected

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a parse error, primary expression expected error in my custom HTML tag at line 8, character 8 :

```
<script>
  function() {
    var sku = document.querySelector(".sku").innerHTML;
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'sku' : sku,
    })
  }
<script>
```

I rewrote my code inside of a function like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418777/google-tag-manager-parse-error-primary-expression/43284117), but it didn't help fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to close your script? Replace your last line with </script> and see if the parse error continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a "/".  The second `<script>` tag should be `</script>`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this was a stupid error. Thank you!